# Could not open the specified zip entry source stream

Tags: java, ftp

I use javaftp to read Excel files from FTP, and then use easyexcel to parse them. I have 12 files in total, of which 8 files are read and parsed successfully, 4 files are read and parsed unsuccessfully all the time, and there is no problem in opening the files locally.

There is no problem to read the project running on the local windows machine. When the project is deployed to the docker container on awsec2, the following problems will appear.

The following error occurs when FTP reads the parsing file. The problem occurs when excel parsing the stream read from FTP.

```
  org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidOperationException: Could not open the specified zip entry source stream
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.openZipEntrySourceStream(ZipPackage.java:205)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.openZipEntrySourceStream(ZipPackage.java:187)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.openZipEntrySourceStream(ZipPackage.java:161)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:142)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:295)
    at com.alibaba.excel.analysis.v07.XlsxSaxAnalyser.readOpcPackage(XlsxSaxAnalyser.java:141)
    at com.alibaba.excel.analysis.v07.XlsxSaxAnalyser.<init>(XlsxSaxAnalyser.java:58)
    at com.alibaba.excel.analysis.ExcelAnalyserImpl.choiceExcelExecutor(ExcelAnalyserImpl.java:92)
    at com.alibaba.excel.analysis.ExcelAnalyserImpl.<init>(ExcelAnalyserImpl.java:45)
    at com.alibaba.excel.ExcelReader.<init>(ExcelReader.java:143)
    at com.alibaba.excel.read.builder.ExcelReaderBuilder.build(ExcelReaderBuilder.java:270)
    at com.alibaba.excel.read.builder.ExcelReaderBuilder.doReadAll(ExcelReaderBuilder.java:274)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
  Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 134582 but got 134589 bytes)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readEnd(ZipInputStream.java:384)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:196)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile$ThresholdInputStream.read(ZipSecureFile.java:220)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource$FakeZipEntry.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:132)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:56)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.openZipEntrySourceStream(ZipPackage.java:203)
```

从FTP读取文件代码如下：

```
 ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(directory);
 ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
 return ftp.retrieveFileStream(downloadFile);
```

解析Excel文件方法:

```
 EasyExcel.read(inputStream, DGBBExcelModel.class, new AnalysisEventListener<DGBBExcelModel>() {
            @Override
            public void invoke(DGBBExcelModel excelModel, AnalysisContext analysisContext) {
                excelModel.setSourceFile(fileName);
                result.add(excelModel);
                if(result.size() >= 1000){
                    deliverGoodsRecordService.addBatch(result);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void doAfterAllAnalysed(AnalysisContext analysisContext) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).doReadAll();
```

Comment: Is the FTP connection using binary mode by default?  If not, have you set it to use binary mode?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error with my Excel file.

I was using a copy component at an application which resulted in the copied file being corrupt.

I believe what you're doing has also caused the file to be corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I've just updated `poi-ooxml` and `poi` from version `3.17` to `4.1.2`.

That solved the problem.